# Random class in Java

Tags: java, random

I'm making a reservation system using Java, and I want to create random ID numbers. (The code I'm going to show isn't all the code in my class, its just the stuff that's relevant.)

I have named a field randomGenerator, which is a Random object and declared it in my constructor:

```
public class ReservationSystem {
     private Random randomGenerator;

     public ReservationSystem() {
           randomGenerator = new Random();
     }
```

And then this is the method that I am having difficulty with:

```
     public void generateCustomerID(String id, int numbersInID) {
     //incNumber stands for incremented number
     int incNumber = 1;
     //create a new array of numbers as big as the user has defined
     int[] numbers = new int[numbersInID];
     while(numbersInID < (incNumber +1)) {
         //add a new number to the array between 0 and 10
         numbers[incNumber] = randomGenerator.nextInt(10);
         incNumber++;
     }
     System.out.print(id);
     for(int number: numbers)
         System.out.print(number);
 }
```

In my application I have given these values:

```
  public class Application { 
       public static void main(String[] args) {
               reserve.generateCustomerID("AB-", 3);
        }
  }
```

And I have been receiving the output **AB-000**.

Comment: I don't understand why you try to generate the number digit by digit. If you need a 3-digit number, just ask for a random number from 0-999. However, you have a more fundamental issue with your approach, which is that it **will not detect ID collisions!**

Comment: I have thought about that! How would I go about making a truly unique number?

Comment: If you want the numbers to be random, you simply have to keep grabbing a new random number each time you detect a collision. This will slow down to a grind once you are about to run out of numbers. A different approach is to keep a list of unassigned numbers, pick a random one and then remove it each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Indexes of arrays begin from 0, not 1, in Java.
- The condition `numbersInID < (incNumber +1)` is wrong and the loop body won't be executed when `numbersInID` is 3.

Try this:

```
public void generateCustomerID(String id, int numbersInID) {
    //incNumber stands for incremented number
    int incNumber = 0;
    //create a new array of numbers as big as the user has defined
    int[] numbers = new int[numbersInID];
    while(incNumber < numbersInID) {
        //add a new number to the array between 0 and 10
        numbers[incNumber] = randomGenerator.nextInt(10);
        incNumber++;
    }
    System.out.print(id);
    for(int number: numbers)
        System.out.print(number);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
while(numbersInID < (incNumber +1)) { // ← *here*
     //add a new number to the array between 0 and 10
     numbers[incNumber] = randomGenerator.nextInt(10);
     incNumber++;
 }
```

It should be while `numbersInID` is *bigger* than `incNumber`:

```
int incNumber = 0;
while(numbersInID > incNumber) {
     //add a new number to the array between 0 and 10
     numbers[incNumber] = randomGenerator.nextInt(10);
     incNumber++;
 }
```

Comment: @GeorginaBeckett This code will randomize only the center digit of the three. Are you sure this is what you want?